# Unable to pass argument to console application, are there flaws in my thinking?

Tags: c#, command, line

I've created a console application that takes a sample text file in and processes it. This works fine when I'm debugging it through Visual Studio but when I attempt to run it from the command line the argument is not passed.

My understanding is that I should be able to run the application by calling it and passing the argument like :

application argument

Which in my case would be something like this :
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\ConsoleApplication2.application C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Sample.txt

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

However doing this generates the following exception :
 "Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at ConsoleApplication2.TestProgram.Main(String[] args)"

The argument should be access through the C# code as follows

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            // Read the file as one string.
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@args[0]);
...
...
rest of method here
...
...
```

}

Comment: Why is your application's extension *application*?

Comment: You aren't missing anything (besides a potential permissions issue) what happens when you run that?

Comment: I get the following message

"Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at ConsoleApplication2.TestProgram.Main(String[] args)"

I'm under the assumption that this is because no argument is actually passed into the application. It should be noted this is my first time working with either C# or Visual Studio so I'm kind of feeling my way around everything.

Comment: Please show the accessor code then

Comment: The relevant portion of code should be as follows, 
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            // Read the file as one string.
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@args[0]);
....
....

Comment: In the question :) Also putting the exception in the question would be good. Use the little "edit" link

Comment: Ok, if you comment out everything but the first line, does it still break? Put another way, does the first writeline run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me solve this. The problem stemmed from the file I was trying to run. I had published an application through visual studio when I was wanting to run an exe from the command prompt.

Great first experience here ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should print out the first argument to the console if you run it from a command prompt:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(args.Length > 0)
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    }
}
```

- Build the application in Visual Studio.
- Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and choose "Open Folder in File Explorer"
- Browse to the bin/Debug or bin/Release folder or whatever build configuration you are using
- Paste the path to the **.exe** into a command prompt and run it:

[image]